# Shorter way of entering "python c:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject mysite"

Tags: python, django

Is there a shorter way of entering "python c:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject mysite"? My guess would be adding it to a path of some kind, but I'm not entirely sure which path or how to actually do it.

I'm running Windows 7. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [How to install Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/):

> On Windows, you might need to adjust your `PATH` environment variable to
>   include paths to Python executable and additional scripts. For
>   example, if your Python is installed in `C:\Python27\`, the following
>   paths need to be added to `PATH`:
>
> ```
> C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;
> ```

Comment: Which PATH is it, though? I have a "Path" in user variables, and a "Path" in system variables. Even adding "C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;" to both still doesn't seem to work. Take a look at this screenshot: http://d.pr/i/NL4z

Comment: I haven't used Windows much but I would assume that system path is for everyone and user path is for your user, where your user will overwrite system path. Try rebooting or logging in and out.

Comment: No need to log out or reboot, but you do need to restart your command prompt.

Comment: As far as user vs. system it does not matter. Both will work and Rickard is right about the scope. Since python is installed as a system-wide app I would suggest modifying the system path instead of the user path, but if you are the only user on the machine it really doesn't matter.

Comment: Can't believe I forgot to restart command prompt... Thanks a lot, guys! All works as it should now.